# What is the QM equivalent of induction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, induction, strong-correlated

And regarding electron correlations, reciprocally what QM ones are strictly due to classical induction and near field effects?

Edit: thanks to whoever thinks necessary to downvote questions without even caring explaining why. 
Now, regarding the comment asking about which system I was thinking about, actually I was thinking of several things. I came accross papers that describe correlations between electrons orbiting a single nucleus, and I wondered how much of said correlations are comparable to the classical induction observed between cables when one is put in motion by an electrical pulse and the other one is induced to a current as well (ampere effect or whatever the exact name). More generally I would like to know if said «correlations» are the main way of QM to represent induction of motion in charged particles from other charged particles, or if correlations are broader, narrower, different, etc.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? What sort of system are you thinking about here?

Comment: I will edit accordingly.